# Rearranging order of elements in python list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following list in python:

```
[(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765), (1.0, 0.4980392156862745, 0.054901960784313725), (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313), (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392), (0.5803921568627451, 0.403921568627451, 0.7411764705882353), (0.5490196078431373, 0.33725490196078434, 0.29411764705882354), (0.8901960784313725, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7607843137254902), (0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745), (0.7372549019607844, 0.7411764705882353, 0.13333333333333333), (0.09019607843137255, 0.7450980392156863, 0.8117647058823529)]
```

It contains of multiple tuples.

How can I rearrange it so that all the elements at even number positions are moved to the end of the list? Not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: What's the expected result?  Do you want `[(0.12156862745098039, 0.7058823529411765, 0.4666666666666667), (1.0, 0.054901960784313725, 0.4980392156862745), ...]` ?

Comment: And what counts as an even numbered position? Do you just mean the second element in every tuple? Or are you counting continually between the tuples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use slicing, and specify a step value of 2 for alternate values.

So for example:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(l[1::2] + l[::2])
```

Result is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 6]
```

That is, all the values at odd indices followed by all the values at even indices, with the index counting from 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply append a list containing only the even elements to a list containing only the odd elements. The even and odd elements are extracted using array slicing.

If you consider the first element to be even (because the index, 0, is even)

```
new = data[1::2] + data[::2]
```

If you consider the first element to be odd (it's at position 1 and 1 is odd), you would reverse the order

```
data[::2] + data[1::2]
```

And for an example

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
new = data[1::2] + data[::2]

# [1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: and if you don't want to produce intermediary list, you can use chain and islice from itertools as `new=list(chain(islice(data,1,None,2),islice(data,0,None,2)))`